# Why does my iTunes 11 won't work on os x lion 10.7?

Tags: macos, itunes

When I open my iTunes it will say iTunes cannot open because of an item

```
Process:         iTunes [3382]
Path:            /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
Identifier:      com.apple.iTunes
Version:         11.0 (11.0)
Build Info:      iTunes-1100099063000000~1
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [188]

Date/Time:       2012-12-06 01:31:03.118 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7 (11A390)
Report Version:  8
Sleep/Wake UUID: CA52DB83-6721-402C-AD84-FEB26ABFEA59

Interval Since Last Report:          14029 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           10
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   9
Anonymous UUID:                      A8E41D02-37C7-4336-831E-E7F47E84DECF

Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
@executable_path/../Frameworks/iPodUpdater.framework/Versions/A/iPodUpdater

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/iPodUpdater.framework/Versions/A/iPodUpdater
  Referenced from: /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
  Reason: unsafe use of @executable_path in /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes with restricted binary

Binary Images:
       0x1055a4000 -        0x10696ffef  com.apple.iTunes (11.0 - 11.0) <B59F624F-D66C-374E-8036-5866262DC87F> /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
    0x7fff651a4000 -     0x7fff651d91ff  dyld (195 - ???) <71093406-21CF-3DBE-A001-802259ED5300> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBook7,1, BootROM MB71.0039.B0B, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 2 GB, SMC 1.60f5
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 1 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142323837334648532D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 1 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142323837334648532D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 5.100.198.11 )
Bluetooth: Version 2.5.0b13, 2 service, 12 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545025B9SA02, 250.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0x24600000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06600000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0x06630000 / 6
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0236, 0x06300000 / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're still seeing this problem, [try downloading the standalone iTunes installer here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/). Run it, reboot for good measure, and see if that helps.